# CSS Hover Menu Issues

Tags: jquery, css

Im working with a css hover menu on a netsuite website. Im using two pieces of code that are not mine and im having trouble sifting through all of the horrible horrible code to get it working right (no time to rewrite).

The menu in question is here: http://www.gardensandhomesdirect.co.uk/menutest

I have it sitting in the middle of the column fine, after some tweaking but want it to be the same width as the column rather than sitting in the middle using its own width.

When I set the width to 180px, it moves out to the right rather than stretching and there is a left hand padding that I cannot find anywere!

I think its just something im missing and is right in front of me!

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Are you referring to the breadcrumb menu, to the "menutest" box, or to the horizontal navbar just beneath the page banner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the width of you `<div id="leftnav">` to `100%` and the padding on your `<ul>` to `0`. That does it for me in Firebug.